# Selecting an option in drop down menu one determines list available in the second drop down menu

Tags: html, jsp, drop-down-menu

I want to make the contains of a second drop down menu dependent on what is selected in the the first. In my case wish to do it for a car selection option. i.e when the car make is selected this then populates the model drop down menu with the relevant models.

As there are a lot of makes of car I would like to keep it concise if possible I presume arrays of models for each make is the solution but how do implement this.
I have look at various solutions and cannot find a suitable answer to this, any suggestions/examples would be gratefully appreciated.

I am using jsp.

```
Make:<select>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can have hidden divs with the models of the appropriate cars for each make, that appear or disappear based on the selected make or you could make an ajax call to retrieve them from somewhere else?

Comment: Would you have an example or a link to a good example of the ajax call method if it is a tidy way of doing it. I have a database I am using for a user profile function, I could also create a table of makes and models maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with some simple JS and css ( here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N7Q57/1/)

```
Make:
<select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option selected value="Choose">Choose</option>
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
</select>       

<div id="brands">
<select class="audi">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>            
</select>
<select class="bmw">
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>            
</select>
</div
```

the jQuery

```
$("#cars").change(function () {
    var string = "";
    string =  $("select#cars option:selected").text();
    if (string == "Audi"){
        $("#brands .bmw").hide();
        $("#brands .audi").show();
        $("#brands").show();
    } else if (string == "BMW"){
        $("#brands .audi").hide();
        $("#brands .bmw").show();
        $("#brands").show();
    }

})
```

and the CSS:

```
#brands{
    display: none;
}
```